# export links of the web with cherio (twice) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to get the links of one page and enter one of those links and get the links to the new page again.

I worked with Cherio and the problem is that getting the links of the second page is encountered with an error.

My code:

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'https://www.aparat.com/search/' + args[1];

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
 var $ = cheerio.load(body);
 links = $('a');
 $(links).each(function(i, link) {
  var href = $(link).attr('href');
  linkss.push(href);
  //console.log(array);
 });
});

const videolists = linkss.filter((word) => (word = '/v/'));

url = 'https://www.aparat.com' + videolists[0];
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
 $ = cheerio.load(body);
 links = $('a');
 $(links).each(function(i, link) {
  var href = $(link).attr('href');
  linksss.push(href);
 });
});
```

Error :

music\node_modules\cheerio\lib\parse.js:69
var oldParent = node.parent || node.root,
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
at Function.exports.update (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\node_modules\cheerio\lib\parse.js:69:26)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\node_modules\cheerio\lib\parse.js:19:11)
at Function.exports.load (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\node_modules\cheerio\lib\static.js:27:14)
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\index.js:56:33)
at self.callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\Aparat music\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)

Comment: perhaps you should consider adding the error the question. just saying that you have an error isn't enough.